# Java application - Read values from text file, add to arraylist

Tags: java, android, delimiter

I'm working on a multiple choice quiz application in Android Studio, and inside a text file I have the answers to each question, as well as their corresponding questions. This is my first attempt at such a task, so apologies in advance for code that may be considered sloppy.

This is what I have for my text file:

Java, What language is most commonly used for Android application development?

Android Studio/Eclipse, Which of these programs is often used for Android application development?

2005, In what year did Google acquire Android?

(There are several more, but this should get the point across.)

The first string before the comma is what I'm trying to add to arrayListTerms, and the string following the comma to arrayListDef. Here's my code so far:

```
    public class ActivityTwo extends AppCompatActivity {
int sizeOfArray;
String[][] qAndA;//Stores Questions and Answers
String[] temp;
ArrayList<String>arrayListTerms;
ArrayList<String>arrayListDef;
HashMap<String, String> qMatch = new HashMap<>();//Matches correct answer with current question
public static final String TAG =" ";

public ActivityTwo() {
    arrayListDef = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayListTerms = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    try {
        InputStream myInputStream = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.textfile);
        BufferedReader myBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myInputStream));
        String str = myBufferedReader.readLine();

        while((str != null)) {
            temp = str.split(",");
            arrayListTerms.add(temp[0]);
            arrayListDef.add(temp[1]);
            //qMatch.put(temp[1], temp[0]);

        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Textfile Loaded.");
        myBufferedReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to open text file.");
    } catch (IOException ex){
        Log.e(TAG, "Error reading text file.");
}

    Collections.shuffle(arrayListDef);
    sizeOfArray = arrayListDef.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using file.io to read the file, point it to the location, and you should be able to then upt the input from that into array list.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while((str != null)) {
            temp = str.split(",");
            arrayListTerms.add(temp[0]);
            arrayListDef.add(temp[1]);
            //qMatch.put(temp[1], temp[0]);

        }
```

To

```
String line = "";
    while((line = str) != null) {
                temp = line.split(",");
                arrayListTerms.add(temp[0]);
                arrayListDef.add(temp[1].trim()); //eliminate space after ','
                //qMatch.put(temp[1], temp[0]);

            }
```

You need to initialize an empty string then fill it in the `while` condition.